# How can I convert large jpgs (15000 x 10840px) to video?

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, quicktime

Whenever I try the command

```
ffmpeg -y -r 1 -i File01.jpg -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

I get the failing result:

```
[swcaler @ 000000000347fe0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0000000002da3c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000000002da3c0] frame MP size (938x678) > level limit (36864)
```

and a corrupt file which cant be read.
Is there a maximum size of the resolution that can be created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's way more than h.264 can handle. The maximum resolution for h.264 is 4096×2304 with Level 5.1 or 5.2.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264#Levels

There are lossless codecs who can theoretically handle this video resolution but it would make no sense to do this. There is no hardware capable of playing videos in this resolution at any acceptable frame rate.
Atleast none that is in any way affordable by a normal human being.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I see it was a bad choice using h.264 codec. I have tried again now with the mjpeg codec and now I'm at least one step further from where I was before. That is, ffmpeg now encodes the files without error messages to something that looks legit and identifies itself as a 15000x10840px video but fails to play in VLC, Mplayer, Windows Media Player.
`ffmpeg -r 10 -i File01.jpg -c:v mjpeg out.mp4`

Comment: It would be helpful to know WHY you want to do this. Again it makes no sense.
You might also want to ditch the mp4 container, its only really suited for h264. AVI or MKV are more suitable for generic codecs.

Comment: I have also just realised that there is a tool for Mac that lets me encode the jpegs to videos of up to 10.000px. That's at least something, but I would hope to get the last 5000px in there as well somehow. http://www.dayofthenewdan.com/projects/time-lapse-assembler-1/

Comment: Ahh yes, it is an idea for an effect in a music video. We borrowed a 80Mpix camera an have shot timelapse with it. By having the large raw video file we hope that Final Cut Pro X will accept it, downsize it to fit 1080p, but because the original is so much larger it will allow us to zoom very far into the image for effect.

Comment: In that case you don't want a video file that makes it even more difficult, you want an image sequence which you already have. Though Final Cut is unable to do this, it has a limit of 4000x4000px.
Only solution would be After Effects (or maybe Nuke), it can handle files of up to 30000x30000px and loves image sequences.
http://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/preparing-importing-still-images.html

Comment: If you don't have After Effects but work non-commercially you can use the 30 day Adobe Creative Cloud trial, it offers a full version of all Adobe CC products.